# JWT implementation with out Oauth

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, jwt

I want to create an applicacion with angular js and REST services with JWT and out oauth. I want to know how to implement refresh token or the way to generate a token for a week for example, what I have to do?
The architecture is: Java , REST, Angular.js and Bootstrap

```
user send login and password 
the server return token 
app user token for access to rest api 
rest return result
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s definitely possible to implement a token authentication scheme without implementing the entire OAuth framework.  Your solution would need to have the following characteristics:

- It needs to exchange credentials for access tokens and refresh tokens (password grant flow)
- The tokens you create should be signed with a key that is private to the server
- Authenticate requests that present an access token.  It needs to verify access tokens by asserting that the signature is valid and the token is not expired
- It needs to issue new access tokens if a valid refresh token is presented (refresh token grant flow)
- Access tokens should have a shorter lifetime then refresh tokens
- It should reject refresh tokens if the refresh token has been revoked (you need to maintain a blacklist of revoked tokens.
- It should do extra checks when the refresh token is being used to get a new access token: is the account still enabled? Or any other check that is relevant to your business logic.

An open-source solution is [Kong](https://getkong.org/).

If you’d like to offload this infrastructure, you can consider a product like [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com/) which can add the Oauth2 token framework to an existing application via our [Java Integrations](https://docs.stormpath.com/java/).  Disclaimer: I work at Stormpath and I think that access tokens and refresh tokens are the best!